# Set clientHeight and scrollHeight of ref.current in React Enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I have a callback on an element rendered by my function component, and I want to test that this callback is triggered on click. However, this element is only rendered when clientHeight and scrollHeight of a ref are different, but both of these values are returning as 0 (as seen when I log to the console from within useLayoutEffect) during these tests. How can I set the values of ref.current.clientHeight and ref.current.scrollHeight to different nonzero values for the purposes of this test?

Here is my component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    
const MyComponent = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<MyComponentProps>) => {
    const ref: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement> = React.CreateRef();
    const { myCallBack } = props;
    const [showItem, setShowItem] = React.useState(false);

    React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current && ref.current.clientHeight < ref.current.ScrollHeight) {
            setShowItem(true);
        }
    }, [ref]);

    const someAction = (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => {
        myCallBack();
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div ref={ref}>
                <p>Some text...</p>
            </div>
            {showItem && <div><p class="some-class" onClick={someAction}>Some more text...</p></div>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Here is my test:

```
describe("my tests", (() => { 
  it("my test", async () => {
    let myCallBackMock = jest.fn();
    let wrapper = mount(
        <MyComponent myCallBack={myCallBackMock} />
    );
    wrapper.find(".some-class").simulate("click", { type: "click" });
    expect(myCallBackMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

This is the error message I receive:

```
Method "stimulate" is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
```

Comment: Don't see the error

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jestjs uses jsdom as its test environment. JSDOM has no layout engine. See [Unimplemented parts of the web platform](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#unimplemented-parts-of-the-web-platform)

> **Layout**: the ability to calculate where elements will be visually laid out as a result of CSS, which impacts methods like `getBoundingClientRects()` or properties like `offsetTop`.

So it will return zeros for many layout-related properties such as `element.clientHeight`.

In this case, we have to mock `ref` and its properties. The `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` properties in your case. So that the `showItem` state will be set to true on the component mount.

Even though we have to mock `React.createRef`, we just add properties and values to it in the `ref.current` setter function and return it rather than a totally fake `ref`. This means `ref.current` still references the HTML div element, not the fake JS object.

E.g.

`MyComponent.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface MyComponentProps {
  myCallBack(): void;
}
export const MyComponent = ({ myCallBack }: React.PropsWithChildren<MyComponentProps>) => {
  const ref: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement> = React.createRef();
  const [showItem, setShowItem] = React.useState(false);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log('clientHeight: %s, scrollHeight: %s', ref.current?.clientHeight, ref.current?.scrollHeight);
    if (ref.current && ref.current.clientHeight < ref.current.scrollHeight) {
      setShowItem(true);
    }
  }, []);

  const someAction = (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => {
    myCallBack();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={ref}>
        <p>Some text...</p>
      </div>
      {showItem && (
        <div>
          <p className="some-class" onClick={someAction}>
            Some more text...
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

`MyComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';

export function createFCRefMock(props: { [propName: string]: any }) {
  const ref = { current: {} };
  const refKey = Symbol('ref');
  Object.defineProperty(ref, 'current', {
    set(current) {
      // intercept the process of setting ref.current
      if (current) {
        Object.entries(props).forEach(([prop, value]) => {
          Object.defineProperty(current, prop, { value });
        });
      }
      this[refKey] = current;
    },
    get() {
      return this[refKey];
    },
  });
  return ref;
}

describe('my tests', () => {
  it('my test', async () => {
    const myCallBackMock = jest.fn();
    const ref = createFCRefMock({ clientHeight: 10, scrollHeight: 20 });
    jest.spyOn(React, 'createRef').mockReturnValueOnce(ref);
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent myCallBack={myCallBackMock} />);
    wrapper.find('.some-class').simulate('click');
    expect(myCallBackMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/73060890/MyComponent.test.tsx (11.738 s)
  my tests
    ✓ my test (73 ms)

  console.log
    clientHeight: 10, scrollHeight: 20

      at stackoverflow/73060890/MyComponent.tsx:11:13

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |    78.57 |     100 |     100 |                   
 MyComponent.tsx |     100 |    78.57 |     100 |     100 | 11-12             
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.354 s
```